# iOS: disable/remove FirebaseAnalytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I update 'Google/Analytics' from CocoaPod and get FirebaseAnalytics.

After that, each time I run project, the FirebaseAnalytics turns out many error loggings.

Currently I don't use this library and want to remove it. Unfortunately I can't find any way to disable / remove it out of Pod.

Here is the Podfile configuration

```
target 'myApp' do
    inhibit_all_warnings!
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
end
```

Console log:

```
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Debug mode is on
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeRun.html')
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Debug logging enabled
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Firebase Analytics is monitoring the network status
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Uploading data. Host: https://play.googleapis.com/log
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics disabled
...
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Network status has changed. code, status: 2, Connected
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Network status has changed. code, status: 2, Connected
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://play.googleapis.com/log
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Cancelling authentication challenge for host. Host: https://play.googleapis.com/log
<FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Encounter network error. Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log}
...
```

**UPDATE:**
I also try to add FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = false in Info.plist but it doesn't work either.

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To disable the collection of data by Firebase Analytics in your app, see the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#temporarily_disable_collection_1).

In summary, to disable temporarily, set `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED` to `NO` in the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` file. To disable permanently, set `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED` to `YES` in the same plist file.

Comment: I implemented this article yesterday and FireBase Analytics is disabled ( show in console log). But the error keep raising infinitive. But it's gone today. So weird..
Btw, you answer help me know more about disabling FA. It works!

Comment: Setting `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_ENABLED` to `NO` in my Info.plist seems to have no effect. I still get `<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled` in the console. I must be missing something...

Comment: The instructions have now been updated as per this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/rved9bIBT0g).

Comment: Please if I disable Firebase will this impact Google Analytics?

Comment: ATTENTION STEVE - it is unclear if you do this in Info.plist, or in GoogleServices-Info.plist.  The current documentation states Info.plist.  Please clarify!

Answer (score 15):

## For 2018

For 2018, you Info.plist will have entries like this:

```
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED</key>
<string>NO</string>
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED</key>
<string>YES</string>
<key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

It seems to be in Info.plist, **NOT** GoogleServices-Info.plist.

Answer (score 6):

I recently ran into a similar issue. I'm using Google Analytics but do not want or need Firebase analytics, which is installed by default if you follow the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift). After searching through the podspecs. I found that the `Google/Analytics` subspec has a dependency on `Google/Core`. The `core` subspec in turn depends on `FirebaseAnalytics` which is why it is getting installed.

I noticed, however, that the `Analytics` subspec also depends on the `GoogleAnalytics` cocoapods.

So I changed my Podfile from:

```rb
target 'myApp' do
    inhibit_all_warnings!
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
end
```

To this:

```
target 'myApp' do
    inhibit_all_warnings!
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
end
```

As a result, the `Google/Analytics.h` umbrella header is no longer available, and you need to include the correct headers manually or create your own umbrella header with the following includes:

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceFields.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProduct.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProductAction.h"
#import "GAIEcommercePromotion.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAILogger.h"
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
```

If you're doing this in a Swift project, you'll need to add these files to your [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) in place of the umbrella header.

In my opinion, this is a small price to pay to not be forced to install the FirebaseAnalytics cocoapod.

#### Update

Although Google's docs haven't been updated, their [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/8/b/3/Google/3.1.0/Google.podspec.json#L5) now tells you to use the `GoogleAnalytics` pod directly

Comment: Perfect solution! This even excludes the Firebase libraries from my build too. Thanks for helping me kill Firebase!

Comment: Btw I also needed `#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAIFields.h>`

Comment: Thanks @Fraser, I updated to include a little more information regarding the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Those logs are not actually from Firebase Analytics but the Firebase Core SDK (based on the URL that it sent to). Therefore, disabling the Firebase Analytics will not eliminate those logs. I guess there was a problem with the device network that the requests from Firebase SDK were cancelled.

Comment: the Great firewall

Comment: Ah. So calls to play.googleapis.com come from the Firebase Core SDK library?

Answer (score 1):

Set the Android platform to true for Google Analytics

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="true" />
```