# Disable Firebase in development mode in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase in my android project. Wanted to know how to disable it in development mode. All crashes and usage/events are being logged and messing up with actual analytics.

Any better way to disable this in development mode?

Comment: As far as i know only option to create 2 different projects for dev and prod environments

Comment: :( No better way?

Comment: That **is** the better way. But otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518212/how-to-disable-remove-firebaseanalytic

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Checkout https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true" />
```

To do this automatically add the following line to manifest:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
        android:value="@bool/FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_DEACTIVATED"/>
```

Set different value of boolean for debug and release in your app/build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        resValue("bool", "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_DEACTIVATED", "true")
    }
    release {
        resValue("bool", "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_DEACTIVATED", "false")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

I also had to add `tools:replace="android:value"` to the AndroidManifest.xml part:
(if using react-native-firebase)
eg: 
`<meta-data tools:replace="android:value" android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="@bool/FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_DEACTIVATED"/>`

Answer (score 19):

Add this line to your manifest file while development.

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="true" />
```

For more details check https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics

Comment: Even better, add a property to Gradle to handle it automatically: resValue("bool", "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_DEACTIVATED", "true") such as was suggested for Crashlytics here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44452585/945247

Comment: how to enable it back?

Answer (score 5):

It would be better to separate your dev and prod environments instead of disabling things completely.  You have options on how to implement this, so you can choose what suits your team the best.  This blog post details your options: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class MyApp extends Application {
        public static boolean isDebuggable;

        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            isDebuggable = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
            FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(!isDebuggable);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Play Services / Firebase 11+, we can programmatically disable the Firebase Crashlytics at runtime.

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

To disable Firebase Crashlytics in Debug builds:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG);
```

or for better readability:

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### To disable crashlytics and analytics

###### in manifest

```
<meta-data
   android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
   android:value="${crashlyticsCollectionEnabled}" />

<meta-data 
   android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" 
   android:value="${analyticsCollectionEnabled}" />
```

###### in gradle

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
       manifestPlaceholders["crashlyticsCollectionEnabled"] = false
       manifestPlaceholders["analyticsCollectionEnabled"] = false
    }
    
    release {
       manifestPlaceholders["crashlyticsCollectionEnabled"] = true
       manifestPlaceholders["analyticsCollectionEnabled"] = true
    }
}
```

you can check from [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android&hl=tr#temporarily_disable_collection) - [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable-reporting) - [Inject build variables into the manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#inject_build_variables_into_the_manifest)