# Disable firebase analytics by default

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics

How can I disable firebase analytics by default?
I know I have setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled for temporary enable or disable.When I open an application my firebase analytics is enabled. Is there a way to disable it by default?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518212/how-to-disable-remove-firebaseanalytics. The first link in that answer points to a page describing how to [permanently disable collection](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#permanently_deactivate_collection).

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen very much, this was useful.