# How to disable FirebaseAnalytics or Crashlytics completely

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I've integrated Crashlytics in my app. I want to disable it.

I've read replies here [How to disable/remove FirebaseAnalytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518212/how-to-disable-remove-firebaseanalytics)

I've tried the accepted answer fix but it doesn't completely disable Firebase login.

How do I completely disables it so that it doesn't log anything?

Comment: Do you want to disable it temporarily or permanently?

Comment: I want to disable it temporarily so that it doesn't log anything neither in Firebase nor in debug console on XCode.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it
First implement the solution provided on https://stackoverflow.com/a/37529032/11038684

Then set FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled (Boolean) to NO in info.plist