# Canonical way to disable analytics in flutter debug build

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-analytics

I have a flutter app using `firebase` and `google analytics`. My data about `active users` is wrong as I am testing a lot in emulators and google analytics thinks that the installs there are real users. As I often reinstall the app for testing it somehow seems to count it as a new user every time.

As a solution, I'd like to disable google analytics when building the app in debug mode and only activate it when I build it with `--release`.

Does anyone know how do achieve this with a flutter app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you're using Firebase Analytics in Flutter (I don't think there's GA for Flutter). You can use `kReleaseMode` flag when setting `navigatorObservers` of `MaterialApp` and creating `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` instance. Here's how I do it in my app (notice that I also use preferences which allow user to turn on/off analytics, as well as desktop platforms where there's no Firebase support which is why I specifically check for Web, iOS and Android platforms):

```
MaterialApp(
    ...
    navigatorObservers: preferences.isAnalyticsEnabled &&
        kReleaseMode &&
        (kIsWeb || Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS)
        ? [
            FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: FirebaseAnalytics()),
          ]
        : [],
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note: you may need to `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';` to use `kReleaseMode` in your code.

Comment: Is there a solution since `FirebaseAnalyticsObserver` was removed in version 9.0.0?

Comment: In my app I've been using a custom observer instead of FirebaseAnalyticsObserver (in order to track dialog routes not available in standard observer) - haven't noticed the change you've mentioned. You can see the custom Firebase observer here, it's simple and quite generic: https://github.com/maxim-saplin/dikt/blob/master/lib/common/analytics_observer.dart

Comment: @MaximSaplin `navigatorObservers` is not available with `MaterialApp.router`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what you are looking for, but you can remove all the ip-addresses of your debug devices from getting tracked in Google Analytics.

UPDATE: the original answer was for Universal Analytics only. Updated the answer to also include Google Analytics 4 properties.

For the **old Universal Analytics** properties, the instructions according to [this page](https://onlinemediamasters.com/exclude-ip-address-google-analytics/) are:

> Exclude Your IP Address From Google Analytics

> 1. Login to Google Analytics and select your profile
> 2. Select the Admin menu
> 3. Under Account select All Filters
> 4. Click Add Filter
> 5. Give the filter a name (can be anything, I use the IP address)
> 6. Leave Filter Type as predefined
> 7. It should read: Exclude + traffic from the IP addresses + that are equal to
> 8. Enter your IP address

For the **new Google Analytics 4** properties, you can filter out "internal traffic" by following the instructions on [this page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10104470?hl=en):

> 1. In Admin, click Data Streams in the Property column.
> 2. Click Web and then click a web data stream.
> 3. In the web stream details, click Configure tag settings (at the bottom).
> 4. Click Define internal traffic.
> 5. Click Create.
> 6. Enter a name for the rule.
> 7. traffic_type is the only event parameter for which you can define a value. internal is the default value, but you can enter a new value (e.g., emea_headquarters) to represent a location from which internal traffic originates.
> 8. Under IP address > Match type, select one of the operators (e.g., IP address equals).
> 9. Under IP address, enter an address or range of addresses that identify traffic from the location you identified in Step 8. You can enter IPv4 or IPv6 addresses.
> 10. Click Create

Note: before step 4 you might need to first click on "Show more" to see the "Define internal traffic" button.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this idea!

Comment: Surprisingly, there's no such button. The only thing I see is message in the top: `Displaying Filters for Universal Analytics Properties only. Filters cannot be applied to Google Analytics 4 Properties.`

Comment: @Konstantin Kozirev: I updated my answer to also include the new Google ANalytics 4 properties, which have an entirely different approach to exclude you ip-addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out from another answer. To disable the collection of data by Firebase Analytics in your app, see the instructions here.

In summary, to disable temporarily, set FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED to NO in the GoogleServices-Info.plist file. To disable permanently, set FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED to YES in the same plist file.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518212/how-to-disable-remove-firebaseanalytics#:~:text=To%20disable%20the%20collection%20of,in%20the%20same%20plist%20file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518212/how-to-disable-remove-firebaseanalytics#:%7E:text=To%20disable%20the%20collection%20of,in%20the%20same%20plist%20file).

Comment: Yes, I found that. but the plist-file only exists for iOS.