# How to turn off Firebase analytics/crashlytics if I run my app in debug mode?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I started using Firebase I remember it had something like:

```
if (kDebugMode) turnOffFirebase();
```

but I don't find anywhere what is the actual code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical way to disable analytics in flutter debug build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67335331/canonical-way-to-disable-analytics-in-flutter-debug-build)

Comment: Similar to that but not exactly. I don't deal with observers. I could just add it to the main method and it would enable/disable the analytics.

Answer (score 8):

`kDebugMode` is the constant, which added inside foundation lib which tells whether the app is running on `debug mode` or not.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!kDebugMode);
FirebaseAnalytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(!kDebugMode);
```

Comment: For the analytics part, use `FirebaseAnalytics.instance.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(!kDebugMode);`

Comment: It is more interesting to use `kReleaseMode` rather than `!kDebugMode`